# Why does searching for `user:` return all questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

I searched for `user:` accidentally and I got [these results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A) with 17 **million** results:

[image]

Is there some bug here?

Or is this a weird means to query all questions on Stack Overflow?

Comment: This is not a bug. You only searched for all posts by any user.

Comment: Shouldn't that be [`user:*`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A*)?

Comment: Depends. `user:` actually takes a numeric user id and nothing else (search for `user:foo` or `user:qwertynl` and see what happens). The search engine apparently ignores non-numeric (including empty) input and resolves the query into a full scan.

Comment: Need a "status-undefined" tag for these. If you screw up the search operator syntax, I don't know why you would expect it to work since "proper behavior" is only defined for proper usage of the operators.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design.

Your query matched every post that was made by a user. Very similar to searching with an empty string.

Comment: I repeat my comment from above: Shouldn't that be [`user:*`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A*)?

Comment: @qwertynl - It used empty string. And every post's user searched contained at least one empty string.

Comment: @TravisJ except that `user:12` doesn't match `user:12345`, so why should `user:` match all users?

Comment: @Manishearth: In either case, the search term is not especially meaningful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Of course, just saying that it's a misportrayal of the engine. Not important anyway.

Comment: @Manishearth - You are correct that if it were a partial match then 12 would return as part of 12345.It must be some sort of default return all then? If you search for [""](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%22) then you can see the same millions of matches.I wasn't trying to mis-portrait the engine, and my point of containing was conjecture.By observation it seemed that the empty string triggered the large response and so I made that connection. I will say that `user:travis` also returns all results. Perhaps when the user is not an int it falls back to string matching or just returns bulk.